# Virtual data source in Jasper server(combining data sources)

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

When using 2 datasets in my jasper studio and display the contents from data sources in two list's Jasper studio giving result perfectly

But in the Jasper server it is giving an exeption like

```
Caused by: org.teiid.api.exception.query.QueryResolverException: Group specified is ambiguous, resubmit the query by fully qualifying the group name: srm_resources
```

so I will explain what I did in the Server Step by step

1. Created a jdbc data source as virtual data source named "multipledatasource"
2. added 2 data sources named "datasource1" and "datasource"2(datasource1 is the same data source used in building first dataset and datasource2 is the same data source used in building dataset2 in the report)
3. While deploying the report to jasper server from jasper studio I am giving the virtual data source I have developed (which holds those two datasources) named "multipledatasource"

Can anyone help me in finding which step am missing.

Comment: My guess is that you have problem that the db can't identify the schema, try to add schema in your query...